# Refactoring Images in Xcode 7?

Tags: xcode, swift, image, refactoring

It is possible to refactor images in Xcode 7? I have a lot of images and I want to change their names. But I do not want to change every reference to this image manually.

I cannot find anything at Google.

Comment: No SWIFT doesn't providing refactoring as it is in objectiveC until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode can only refactor C and Objective-C code for now. You will have to do the refactoring manually, or simply using Find > Find and Replace in Workspace...

To avoid potential crashes that might be caused if you make a mistake, use [R.swift](https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift), which makes it similar to how it works on Android.

Comment: ...and if you want to batch rename all those files, you can use a free app called NameChanger.